# Using custom loss and predict in Keras

Tags: python, keras

I am creating a custom loss in Keras. Lets assume that we have the following:

```
def a_loss(X):
    a, b = X
    loss = . . . 
    return loss

def mean_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(y_pred - 0 * y_true)
```

And the model goes something like:

```
                             .
                             .
                             .
z1 = Dense(shape1, activation="linear")(conv_something)
z2 = Dense(shape1, activation="linear")(conv_something2)
loss = a_loss([z1, z2])

model = Model(
    inputs=[input1, input2, ..],
    outputs=[loss])

model.compile(loss=mean_loss,optimizer=Adam())
```

Now this hypothetical model compines normally. But when I have to use the trained model to predict something I am using:

```
model.predict(X_dictionary)
```

I am assuming that the output of the above is the `loss`(output of `a_loss` function).Right? If not correct me.

What I want for output of `model.predict` is to be the `z2`. Searching the API u can use multiple outputs:

```
model = Model(
    inputs=[sequence_input_desc, sequence_input_title_positive, sequence_input_title_negative],
    outputs=[loss, z2]
)
```

But the above will train to minimize both `loss` and `z2`. What I want is to train only to minimize `loss` and the predict function to output `z2`. One way checking the doc is to use `loss_weights=[1.0,0.0]` in the `compile` but it doesn't work. It outputs the error `The model expects 2target arrays, but only received one array. Found: array with shape ..`

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After training is done you can simply create a new model that uses the same layers but has a different output:

```
model = Model(
    inputs=[input1, input2, ..],
    outputs=[z2])
```

It will re-use the learned weights as they are stored in the layers, not in the model (it is just a container).

You can then use `model.predict` to get the results as you would normally.

Comment: You mean that just after `model.fit(x,y..)` I can assign `model2 = Model(inputs=[input1,..], outputs=[z2])` and that `model2` will inherit the weights of the trained `model`? Or I need to re-write the architecture of the model again and after call `Model` with the different output?

Comment: If you re-define the "architecture" (the layers) then you will lose the weights. You just need to define a new model as I showed in the answer.

Comment: yea. I figure it out by testing the output of the weights later on.  thank you.